# React-Router with create-react-app not mounting/rendering component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, create-react-app

First let me say I am very new to react and react-router, more specifically react-router-dom. I've got a template admin site I was tasked with using for our site. I've re-organized much of the existing components into their own classes. I have my app.js file, which contains the top navbar, sidebar, and content window styling. Inside this, I've got my router with a switch and routes inside, like so - (this is my app.js file)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PageSidebar from './sidebar/PageSidebar'
import PageContent from './children/PageContent'
import Navbar from './navbar/Navbar'
import Login from './login/Login'
import $ from 'jquery'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import AccountController from './account/AccountController'
import EmployerController from './employer/EmployerController'
import EmployeeController from './employee/EmployeeController'

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        login: false,
        user: null,
        cookies: new Cookies(),
        update: false

    }
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
}


handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    if(localStorage.getItem('user') !== null) {
        console.log('user not null')
        this.setState({
            login: true
        })  
    } else {
        console.log('bad login attempt')
    }

}


renderPage() {
    this.setLoadingTimer()
    return (

        <div>
            <div className="loading-container">
                <div className="loader"></div>
            </div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="main-container container-fluid">
                <div className="page-container">
                    <PageSidebar />
                    <div className="page-content">

                        <div className="page-breadcrumbs">
                            <ul className="breadcrumb">
                                <li>
                                    <i className="fa fa-home"></i>
                                    <a href="">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Tables</a>
                                </li>
                                <li className="active">Simple and Responsive</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="page-header position-relative">
                            <div className="header-title">
                                <h1>
                                    Tables
                                    <small>
                                        <i className="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                        simple and responsive tables
                                    </small>
                                </h1>
                            </div>

                            <div className="header-buttons">
                                <a className="sidebar-toggler" href="" onClick={this.sideBarClick}>
                                    <i className="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a className="refresh" id="refresh-toggler" href="">
                                    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a className="fullscreen" id="fullscreen-toggler" href="" onClick={this.fullScreenClick}>
                                    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <Router>
                            <div className="page-body">
                                <Switch>
                                    <Route exact path="/" component={AccountController}/>
                                    <Route exact path="/employer" component={EmployerController}/>
                                    <Route exact path="/employee/:id" component={EmployeeController}/>
                                </Switch>
                                <div className="horizontal-space"></div>
                            </div>
                        </Router>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
render() {

    if(this.state.cookies.get('etc-usr-cki') == null) {
        this.state.cookies.get('etc-usr-cki')
        return <Login handler={this.handler}/>
    }else {
        return this.renderPage()
    }
}
}

export default App
```

So, after login, the site goes to the 'AccountController' router just fine. When I click on the Link I have created to go to EmployerController, nothing. It changes the url, but it seems nothing else is happening. I've tried forceRefresh on my Router tag, I've passed an update method down and updated the state of app.js, but nothing gets rendered until the page is manually refreshed. 
Below is my AccountController and one of its children responsible for a table which holds the Links I am creating.

AccountController

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SimpleTable from '../children/SimpleTable'
import EmployerTable from './EmployerTable'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class AccountController extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {account : {}}


    this.getEmployers = this.getEmployers.bind(this)
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({account : {
        name : "account name",
        description : "account description",
        employerCount : 44
    }}))
}


getEmployers() {



    return(
        [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Company Name",
                address: "212 Some st.",
                employees: 32
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Another Company Name",
                address: "4545 Some ave.",
                employees: 76
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Yet Another Company Name",
                address: "6543 Some blvd.",
                employees: 122
            }
        ]
    )

    //PULL LIST OF EMPLOYERS
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div className="databox databox-xlg databox-halved radius-bordered databox-shadowed databox-vertical">
                    <div className="databox-top bg-white padding-10">
                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 text-align-left padding-10">
                            <span className="databox-header carbon no-margin">
                                <p>{this.state.account.name}</p>
                            </span>
                            <span className="databox-text lightcarbon no-margin">
                                {this.state.account.description}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="databox-bottom bg-white no-padding">
                        <div className="databox-row row-12">
                            <div className="databox-row row-6 no-padding">
                                <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center bordered-right bordered-platinum">
                                    <span className="databox-text sonic-silver  no-margin">Employees</span>
                                    <span className="databox-number lightcarbon no-margin">
                                        {this.state.account.employerCount}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center bordered-right bordered-platinum">
                                    <span className="databox-text sonic-silver no-margin">1095's</span>
                                    <span className="databox-number lightcarbon no-margin">
                                        344
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center">
                                    <span className="databox-text sonic-silver no-margin">Some Other Data</span>
                                    <span className="databox-number lightcarbon no-margin">286</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <EmployerTable employers={this.getEmployers()} />
        </div>

    )
}

}

export default withRouter(AccountController)
```

and finally, the EmployerTable class below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class EmployerTable extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {employers: []}

    this.eachEmployer = this.eachEmployer.bind(this)
    this.tableRowClickHandler = this.tableRowClickHandler.bind(this)
}



componentWillMount() {
    //HIT API FOR FULL EMPLOYER INFO HERE

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        employers: this.props.employers
    }))
}

tableRowClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let eid = e.target.getAttribute('data-value')

}


eachEmployer(employer, i) {

    return (


                <tr key={employer.id}>
                    <td data-value={employer.id}>
                        {i+1}
                    </td>
                    <td data-value={employer.id}>
                        {employer.name}
                    </td>
                    <td data-value={employer.id}>
                        {employer.address}
                    </td>
                    <td data-value={employer.id}>
                        {employer.employees}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <Link to={'/employer'} className="btn btn-default">
                                View
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>


    )
}

render() {
    return(
        <Router>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div className="well with-header  with-footer">
                        <div className="header bg-blue">
                            Simple Table With Hover
                        </div>
                        <table className="table table-hover">
                            <thead className="bordered-darkorange">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        #
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Address
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Employees
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.props.employers.map(this.eachEmployer)}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <div className="footer">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
}

export default withRouter(EmployerTable)
```

So, as I stated, I'm unable to see any action from clicking my link inside the 'EmployerTable' which should point to my Route inside app.js. When I manually refresh the page, all is good, but obviously this isn't what I'm after. If I've made any obvious or taboo React errors, please feel free to point them out, as I have only been in react for a very short time and away from web for much longer.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

EDIT--

I forgot to add the EmployerController class, as mentioned below. Here it is-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


class EmployerController extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        id : this.props.id
    }

    this.renderEmployerDataBox = this.renderEmployerDataBox.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {

    alert('component did mount')
}

renderEmployerDataBox() {
    return (
        <div className="col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div className="databox databox-xlg databox-halved radius-bordered databox-shadowed databox-vertical">
                <div className="databox-top bg-white padding-10">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 text-align-left padding-10">
                        <span className="databox-header carbon no-margin">Some Company</span>
                        <span className="databox-text lightcarbon no-margin"> Some Company's Description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="databox-bottom bg-white no-padding">
                    <div className="databox-row row-12">
                        <div className="databox-row row-6 no-padding">
                            <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center bordered-right bordered-platinum">
                                <span className="databox-text sonic-silver  no-margin">Employees</span>
                                <span className="databox-number lightcarbon no-margin">510</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center bordered-right bordered-platinum">
                                <span className="databox-text sonic-silver no-margin">1095's</span>
                                <span className="databox-number lightcarbon no-margin">908</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center">
                                <span className="databox-text sonic-silver no-margin">Some Other Data</span>
                                <span className="databox-number lightcarbon no-margin">286</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="databox-row row-6 no-padding">
                            <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center bordered-right bordered-platinum">
                                <a className="btn" href="">Detail</a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center bordered-right bordered-platinum">
                                <a className="btn" href="">Detail</a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="databox-cell cell-4 no-padding text-align-center bordered-right bordered-platinum">
                                <a className="btn" href="">Code Matrix</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


render() {
    return (
        this.renderEmployerDataBox()
    )
}
}

export default withRouter(EmployerController)
```

Comment: Where's the `EmployerController` class?

Comment: I just added it. Thanks for the catch, it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra **Router** tag inside your **Router** tag, which is making the **Link** inside refer to the extra **Router** instead of the one in App.js which you likely wanted to use.

To fix this, simply remove the extra **Router** tags from EmployerTable.js.

```
render() {
    return(
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div className="well with-header  with-footer">
                    <div className="header bg-blue">
                        Simple Table With Hover
                    </div>
                    <table className="table table-hover">
                        <thead className="bordered-darkorange">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Address
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Employees
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.props.employers.map(this.eachEmployer)}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div className="footer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: my word..... I can't thank you enough. I'm sure I would've seen it eventually, but I've been pouring over this for hours and just kept looking past it I guess. Thanks a bunch.